# Check if a Sympy expression simplifies to a constant

Tags: sympy

Is there a way (within Sympy) to check if two expressions differ by a mere constant? In other words, is there something like a `is_constant()` function?

My minimum working example:

```
from sympy import symbols, simplify
x,y = symbols('x y')
expr1 = x+y+1
expr2 = x+y+3
if is_constant(simplify(expr1 - expr2)):
    print('expr2 is just expr1 added to a constant!')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`is_constant()`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.is_constant) method of Sympy objects. For example,

```
(expr1 - expr2).is_constant()
```

> `True`